# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'as_matrix' Why is it error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I execute the code of the official website, I get such an error. Why?
code show as follow:

```
landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(‘F:\OfficialData\faces\face_landmarks.csv’)
n = 65
img_name = landmarks_frame.iloc[n, 0]
landmarks = landmarks_frame.iloc[n, 1:].as_matrix()
landmarks = landmarks.astype(‘float’).reshape(-1, 2)
```

List item

Comment: Which official website? Can you provide a link to the dataset?

Comment: [`pd.DataFrame.as_matrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) has been deprecated since version 0.23.0; you should use [`DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Replace it with DataFrame.to_numpy ()

Comment: I got the error in a different way : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Answer (score 56):

As stated in another answer, the `as_matrix` method is deprecated since 0.23.0, so you should use `to_numpy` instead. However, I want to highlight the fact that `as_matrix` and `to_numpy` have different signatures: [as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) takes a list of column names as one of its parameter, in case you want to limit the conversion to a subset of the original DataFrame; [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) does not accept such a parameter. As a consequence, the two methods are completely interchangeable only if you want to convert the DataFrame in full. If you (as in my case) need to convert a subset of the matrix, the usage would be quite different in the two use cases.

For example let's assume we only need to convert the subset ['col1', 'col2', 'col4'] of our original DataFrame to a Numpy array. In that case you might have some legacy code relying on `as_matrix` to convert, which looks more or less like:

```
df.as_matrix(['col1', 'col2', 'col4'])
```

While converting the above code to `to_numpy` you cannot simply replace the function name like in:

```
df.to_numpy(['col1', 'col2', 'col4'])  # WRONG
```

because `to_numpy` does not accept a subset of columns as parameter. The solution in that case would be to do the selection first, and apply `to_numpy` to the result, as in:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col4']].to_numpy()  # CORRECT
```

Answer (score 22):

The purpose of `as_matrix` method is to

> Convert the frame to its Numpy-array representation.

`as_matrix` method is deprecated since 0.23.0
[0.25.1 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) says : Deprecated since version 0.23.0: Use DataFrame.values() instead

The two alternatives are

1. .values() : Returns numpy.ndarray
2. .to_numpy() : Returns numpy.ndarray

However, `.values()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) gives another warning :- `Warning We recommend using DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.`

I got the error in a slightly different way : `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'`

Answer (score 0):

`as_matrix()` method is deprecated in new versions of pandas library, but alternatively you could use `to_numpy()` method or `.values` attribute. You should note that `values` is an attribute and must be called with dot notation and no parenthesis at the end. Otherwise it will make an error. For example the line of code you mentioned above:

```
landmarks = landmarks_frame.iloc[n, 1:].as_matrix()
```

should be change to:

```
landmarks = landmarks_frame.iloc[n, 1:].values
```

and not to:
`landmarks = landmarks_frame.iloc[n, 1:].values()` --> this makes error